# How to use @Value on Spring non-managed class

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, code-injection

Here my (simplified) code before explaining my problem :

**foo.bar.MyFile**

```
public class MyFile extends MyFileAbstract {

    @Value("${FILE_PATH}")
    private String path;

    [...]
    
    public MyFile(final Date date, final String number, final List<MyElement> elements) {
        this.date = date;
        this.number = number;
        this.elements = elements;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }
    
    [...]
}
```

**foo.bar.MyService**

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    [...]
    
    public String createFolder(MyFileAbstract file) throws TechnicalException {
        
        [...]
        
        String path = file.getPath();
        
        [...]
    }
    
    [...]
}
```

**the call of service**

```
[...]
@Autowired
MyService service;

public void MyMethod() {
    MyFile file = new MyFile();
    service.createFolder(file);
    [...]
}

[...]
```

I use a context XML to configure Spring :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder
        file-encoding="utf-8"
        location="file:///[...]/MyProperties.properties" />

    <context:annotation-config />   
 
    <context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar.classes" />
    
    [...]
</beans>
```

The problem is that the variable `path` is null at runtime in both `MyService` and `MyFile` file when a instantiate `MyFile` to call my service `MyService`.

I am looking a solution to inject my property `${FILE_PATH}` inside `MyFile`.

Here my environment :

- Apache Tomcat 7
- Java 8
- Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE

I have seen that Spring AOP with @Configurable bean could resolve this but don't want to change my Java Agent because I don't want to modify the configuration on the production server.

And I don't know how to use @Service on `MyFile` with my custom constructor.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your MyService

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

and just get the value

```
environment.getProperty("FILE_PATH");
```

After that you can set it to the file if necessary.

Comment: Yep, can be a solution. I could use Value instead of Autowired in my service. Not really "clean" but this is a solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Service
 public class BeanUtilityService implements ApplicationContextAware {

   @Autowired
   private static ApplicationContext context;

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
   }

   public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
    return context.getBean(beanClass);
   }
}
```

Create a Utility class as a service , create a static method and get the bean from the context.Then use that bean to get the properties required

Answer (score -3):

use @PropertySource annotation

```
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties") //use your property file name
public class MyFile extends MyFileAbstract {

    @Value("${FILE_PATH}")
    private String path;

    [...]

    public MyFile(final Date date, final String number, final List<MyElement> elements) {
        this.date = date;
        this.number = number;
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: It won't help because the MyFile is not a bean but created manually.